# Chrome Extension - Execute Javascript Based on HTML Content

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I want to create a simple Chrome Extension that execute javascript when the current tab has HTML node ("Power Boat" for example). How would I determine if the HTML body has the word "Power Boat"? Something like below but for Chrome Extension

```
var findWord = (document.body.innerHtml.match("Power Boat"))
if (findWord.length > 0) { execute some other javascript code}
```